# Alternative to Galternatives

Tags: gui, update-alternatives

Is there an alternative to `galternatives` (a GUI to `update-alternatives`)?

It seems that the package is not maintained since 2015.

Comment: See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856289#8 re. a potential new maintainer.